# Information Architecture: Social Proof

Tags: information-architecture

Here's a high-level blueprint of my website.

[image]

- [**Social proof**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006124189X) (testimonials, interviews) should appear on **which page**?
- I'm considering adding an "**Interesting Facts**" page. The **unique** thing about me is I have a wide knowledge base. I almost always have a relevant story or fact related to a situation and I'm good at random trivia or quizzes. I thought including an "Interesting Facts" page might make my design more emotionally appealing. What's your perspective on this? Kind of like how the Nielsen Norman Group has a [People page](http://www.nngroup.com/about/people/).

Answer (score 5):

Having a full page dedicated to interesting facts about yourself seems a bit over the top and, for me at least, would not inspire confidence in anyone I was reading them about.

If you feel that they are appropriate for your audience and that it may help them to relate, then **include them in your "About Tyler Longan" page.**

Comment: Very insightful, John. One note is that the interesting facts would be about the world, and not about me. How do you feel about Sagmeister's 'Answers' page? http://www.sagmeister.com

Comment: @TylerLangan I think that is a poster example of designers ignoring UX completely.